# pgAdmin 4: Data Ouput tab allows only 1000 rows

Tags: pgadmin

I am using pgAdmin 4.5 on Mac. My data output tab shows only 1000 rows even though the selection shows no limit (and offers no other option).

It seems that the default value is 1000 (from pgAdmin 4.5 doc) despite the option of no limit is shown.

Is this a known bug and should I move to the latest version?

Comment: Seeing same issue on 4.11 on Windows. Agreed looks like a bug

Answer (score 0):

This looks like it might be a bug.

Changing / increasing the below parameter helps to get more data.
It is located in the file config.py pgAdmin4/web folder

```
##########################################################################
# Number of records to fetch in one batch in query tool when query result
# set is large.
##########################################################################
ON_DEMAND_RECORD_COUNT = 1000
```